# Kotlin - parsing json string throws MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am trying to save a value to a jsonb DB column:

```
  val deliveryAddressAsJson = deliveryAddress?.toJson()
  val lat = deliveryAddressAsJson?.get("latitude")
  val lng = deliveryAddressAsJson?.get("longitude")
  val dataJson = jsonObject("comment" to "KARTKOORD:#LE#$lat#$lng# #")
  val values = mapOf(
      "type" to EventType.RESOLVED.dbName,
      "created_by" to ctx.userId,
      "data" to dataJson.toPgObject(),
      "package_id" to packageId
  )

  @Language("PostgreSQL")
  val sql = """insert into package_event(type, created_by, data, package_id) values (:type, :created_by, :data, :package_id)""".trimMargin()

  insert(ctx, sql, values).bind()
```

I can see that the data is saved like this:

```
data -> {Collections$SingletonMap@6348}  size = 1
  key = "data"
  value = {Collections$SingletonMap@6348}  size = 1
     key = "comment"
     value = "KARTKOORD:#LE#59.8098962#10.7809297# #"
```

But, if I try to parse it:

```
  val resolvedPackageEvent = fetchRows(ctx, queryOf("select * from package_event where package_id = ? and type = 'resolved'", packageId)).first()

  val data = parseJson(resolvedPackageEvent.string("data"))
  val deliveryAddress = data.get("comment")
```

I get an exception thrown:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 20 path $.comment
```

If I try to get the value with `jsonObject` method like this:

```
fun Entity.jsonObject(key: String): JsonObject = when (val v = this[key]) {
  is String -> parseJson(v)
  else -> v as JsonObject
}

resolvedPackageEvent.jsonObject("data")
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Collections$SingletonMap cannot be cast to class com.google.gson.JsonObject (java.util.Collections$SingletonMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.google.gson.JsonObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

How should I parse this json string?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not an String. As you can see in the debugger, your data is something like

```
{
  "data": {
    "comment": "KARTKOORD:#LE#59.8098962#10.7809297# #"
  }
}
```

I don't have the gson syntax at hand, so I can't provide precise code for retrieving the value. You can probably do something like

```
val result: JsonObject = parseJson(resolvedConsignmentEvent)
val data: JsonObject = result.get("data")
val deliveryAddress: String = data.get("comment")
```

Comment: parseJson accepts only String as a param: ```fun parseJson(json: String): JsonObject = gson.fromJson(json)```  that is why I am fetching/converting the value to string with string method: ```fun Entity.string(key: String): String = when (val v = this[key]) {
  is String -> v
  else -> v.toString()
}```